# nifi as a producer to kafka: data is not sequential while reading Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, kafka-producer-api, hortonworks-dataflow

I am publishing flowfiles from nifi to kafka, using publishKafka_0_10 processor. While reading datafrom Kafka through code, the sequence of data is not maintained (sorted according to timestamp). My data set is like: timestamp, channel,value.

Just to debug, I am publishing the same flowfiles to phoenix using PutSql and I can see that in Phoenix table, data is sequential (sorted according to time). It would be great if someone explains me why am I not able to read data from kafka sequentially. There is only one partition in topic in kafka. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka only guarantees order within a partition. Since you say this is one partition, then okay.

> My data set is like: timestamp, channel,value.

Message timestamps are simply record *metadata*, (your own timestamps are not passed into the Kafka ProducerRecord class by NiFi). Also, timestamps have no implications on ordering. In other words, if one "late timestamped" message is committed before other of an "earlier" time, then yes it's chronologically out of order, but Kafka just sees the offsets have moved.

> why am I not able to read data from kafka sequentially

You are, but in the order the messages were committed to Kafka.

Your consumer code should extract the record timestamps are reorder them accordingly. For example, Kafka Connect has a Record Timestamp extractor, which can write data into partitioned directories based on this time. I assume your PutSQL processor is reading the sequentially ordered FlowFiles (which have their own timestamps, not the timestamps in your data, unless you ran a ModifyAttribute processor), not using the ConsumeKafka processor?

Comment: I agree. Then is there any processor in nifi, using which I modify data sequence based on my Daa timestamp sequentially while producing flowfiles in Kafka.

Comment: I took a quick look at processor source code, and I think all the PublishKafka ones under 0_10 use the same class to produce, and the timestamp isn't modifiable, as far as I can tell

Comment: It means only solution is, while consuming the messages, reader needs to rearrange them in order?

Comment: When using NiFi, it would appear so. As I mention, Kafka Connect is a framework which respects Kafka message time. Unfortunately, there is no UI like NiFi

Comment: NiFi is going to publish data to Kafka by reading a flow file line-by-line, or record by record, and publishing each one, so it is however the data is organized in the flow file.

Comment: @cricket_007 if NiFi was able to set the timestamp field on each ProducerRecord, are you saying that Kafka would respect this and re-order the data on the broker side? This would only work per commit right? because the log is append-only so it can only possibly re-order a batch of records that are about to be committed.

Comment: @Byran I think OP is asking about the time ordering in the data itself. There's also FlowFile times and Kafka Record times. Looking at the source code, I can say the times of the Kafka records are not directly tied to the FlowFile generation time, or data,  but rather the time at which the Kafka Record is constructed during the transfer. All I'm saying is that, if NiFi could write the timestamp, it would be possible to have matching of the times of the data, or the FlowFile, depending on a configuration option. I'll try not to make significant claims about ordering, since I've not tried it